# Meaning of "de l'esprit"

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, expressions

The phrase is in a passage by  Jean-François Marmontel, therefore possibly 18th century usage.

The full text is:

> En général, la fatuité des musiciens est de croire ne rien devoir a leur poète ; et Grétry, avec de l'esprit, a eu cette sottise au suprême degré.

What does *esprit* mean in this context ?

Comment: Welcome to French.SE! Did you look in any dictionary to try to figure out the meaning? What wasn't clear in them?

Comment: Many thanks for your replies, which are very helpful. I did look up the word in several dictionaries, but couldn't quite get the sense. Clearly Marmontel is being very critical of his former partner for not taking his poetry seriously enough, but I couldn't figure out if he was using esprit in a pejorative or figurative sense. I do not think he means wit in this context. The translation I have come up with so far is: "In general, the stupidity of musicians is to believe they owe nothing to their poet, and Grétry, with some zest, possessed this nonsense to a supreme degree.”

Comment: The writer is Jean-François Marmontel, who was writing about his strained relationship with André-Modeste Grétry.

Answer (score 7):

> Sens 1.
> Être incorporel ou imaginaire.
> Traduction anglais : *ghost*, *spirit*
>
> Sens 2.
> Facultés intellectuelles.
> Exemple : Avoir de l'esprit.
>
> Sens 3.
> Humour, ironie.
> Exemple : Faire de l'esprit.
> Traduction anglais : *wit*
>
> Sens 4.
> Manière de penser, façon de concevoir.
> Exemple : Avoir un esprit cartésien.
> Traduction anglais : *mind*, *spirit*

For this sentence I guess the English translation would be “wit”.

As FredericS said, it's used ironically here.

Comment: I think it's indeed "sens 3" here, but it seems to be used ironically in this sentence, don't you think?

Comment: yep i updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

More often than not, we use it to refer to "wit", but in the context of your sentence, I'd be tempted to say that it was meant in the sense of "with gusto" or "without reserve".

Answer (score 1):

> En général, la fatuité des musiciens est de croire ne rien devoir a leur poète ; et Grétry, avec de l'esprit, a eu cette sottise au suprême degré.

Essayons de réorganiser la phrase, elle même écrite avec beaucoup d'esprit<sup>1</sup> :

> Grétry, avec de l'esprit<sup>2</sup>,  a eu la fatuité  au suprême degré de croire ne rien devoir a son poète.

Donc, tout le *talent*, tout le *génie*, toute l'*intelligence* qui manifeste "l'*esprit*" de Grétry, ne trouve pas grâce au yeux de son détracteur, qui d'une flèche vengeresse (il défend les auteurs contre les musiciens) et ironique réduit les qualités du musicien, qu'il trouve fat, en cendres.

Pour marque l'ironie, je traduirais *avec de l'esprit* par ***avec une subtile***<sup>3</sup> ***intelligence*** le mot à mot ou la traduction par un seul terme n'incluant pas la 'vacherie' de Marmontel qui ne parle pas de "l'esprit de" Grétry, mais de ses dires "fait avec esprit".

---

<sup>1 - Ici un esprit mordant, ravageur : manier l'*ironie* (qui à la vertu d'être imparable) à ce point c'est donner de l'*esprit* à quelqu'un pour démontrer qu'il n'en a pas. On ne peut avoir de l'esprit et être quelqu'un qui dit ou fait des sottises.
L'esprit de Jean-François Marmontel est ici *ironique*.</sup>

<sup>2 - Ici esprit peut avoir à la fois le sens d'*intelligence*, de *talent*, de *finesse*, de *malice* et être même être *spirituel*, il peut aussi refléter l'*intention*, la *volonté*, le *point de vue* (Grétry dit ce qu'il pense "Dans un esprit de vérité") voire le *génie* de l'auteur.</sup>

<sup>3 - *Subtile* incluant ici les notions évoquées dans le <sup>2</sup> ci-dessus, et intelligence donne tout de même une limite à l'esprit qui englobe l'intelligence avec un 'souffle' ou une énergie supérieure.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for these thoughts. It seems to me that Marmontel is being ironic in a diplomatic way, and I wonder if the translation would not be better as: . "In general, the stupidity of musicians is to believe they owe nothing to their poet, and Grétry, in his wisdom, possessed this nonsense to a supreme degree" -- in other words the word wisdom replaces esprit in a spirit of irony.

Comment: *wisdom* est traduit par *sagesse* en français, or quelqu'un de sage possède et l'esprit (l'intelligence subtile) et la connaissance (la conscience de la réalité), il ne peut donc pas se tromper, prendre son ego pour l'Esprit divin. Je choisirais plutôt *intelligence subtile*, car Grétry se croit subtile, alors qu'il tombe dans le panneau de la sotte fatuité, et là, le contre-pied ironique de Marmontel devient vraiment imparable....

Comment: .... N.B. : On ne se croit pas sage, on est sage... ou pas, mais on peut se croire malin, spirituel, intelligent... tant que l'on n'a pas rencontré plus malin, plus spirituel ou plus intelligent que soi... ou que l'on prend ses désirs pour des réalités (sorte de mythomanie).

Comment: I think you are right. I am using wisdom in a colloquial and slightly sarcastic sense -- in English, to say that someone does something in his wisdom means that he believes in what he is doing but that nobody else does.

Comment: @Beejay ... d'où l'impossibilité de traduire littéralement un texte (dans un sens comme dans l'autre), et que la transposition (beaucoup plus facile en version !) est l'art des traducteur, art qu'un robot a beaucoup de mal à copier.